# Count If And / Or Based Criteria In Another Table

Tags: excel

I have two tables:

**Locations**

```
State | MSA | County | City | Zipcode | Count in County
All possible combinations
```

[image]

**Transactions**

```
City | State | Zipcode | ID
```

[image]

I am trying to modify a formula to set a value for "Count in Country" to display the number of transactions in the County. I am not sure how to get Index Match based on multiple criteria or a sum if approach to work.

Comment: can you provide 2-3 lines of example data under your table header, and then provide expected result based on the example data?  Since you are trying to modify a formula what is that formula?  falls under the category of what have you tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need INDEX MATCH for this. A simple `COUNTIF` would do if you just need to check the city, and `COUNTIFS` if you need to count transactions on all City, State, Zipcode.

> Read this
>   [link](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/07/10/excel-countifs-multiple-criteria/)
>   for more details.

Comment: the problem is that for every row, i want to countif based on if the county matches up with the city and the state based on the other table

Comment: That's why you use `COUNTIFS`

Answer (score 0):

This formula should do it:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(1*(LOOKUP(Transactions[City]&Transactions[State],[City]&[State],[County])=[@County]))
```

**One caveat:  The data in the Locations table must be sorted ascending on the CITY column**

---

If that does not work for you then you may want to consider putting the County in a helper column on the Transaction table.  The you can use an INDEX/MATCH array formula in that new column:

```
=INDEX(Locations[County],MATCH([@City]&[@State],Locations[City]&Locations[State],0))
```

This needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done properly Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

Then a simple COUNTIF() in the Locations table will do it:

```
=COUNTIF(Transactions[County],[@County])
```